# Setting Power > Blank Screen to 1 Hour

Tags: 18.04, power-management

[image: Power Settings]

The Power settings screen in Ubuntu 18.04 lets me choose 10 different options for blanking the screen after a certain length of time. Oddly, none of the options are greater than 15 minutes.

I use multiple computers while working and often keep reference material up for 30 minutes to an hour without interacting with the machine. I would really like this timeout to be 1 hour so if I leave the screen does eventually turn off without getting in the way of my workflow.

There must be some way to set this option to an hour. Maybe outside of the settings GUI? Has anyone had any luck?

Also, who uses 12 minutes?! There are lots of options but most of them are completely useless. I would love to find the discussion that ended up with these options. Maybe the idea is to save power, but instead they are going to force many users to use `Never` and waste tons of power.

Comment: I agree, but this strikes me as part of today's thoughtless security obsession. Security is fine, but you can't just throw stuff against the wall and see what sticks. This would be a case in point: "clearly, any time above 15 minutes is so ridiculously insecure that you might as well be on never." But that's like shooting ourselves in the foot to spite our face, because never locking is precisely zero security. And of course if your use case requires a computer to be active for more than 15 minutes without interaction, you're left with no choice but to disable sec. functionality outright.